# According to Regex, the number value I caught with Keyup event when sending is not written properly to inside to input

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I write numeric value in input, and Regex catch up value and replace according to my regex. But it does not work correctly. I use the keyup event when I write numeric value and I need to fix from myregex correctly for every keyup events. It worked correctly until four digits, after that it's not working correctly.

**I expected inside the input:**
592,500,000

**But It return like this error inside the input** : 5,9,2,5,0,0,,000

You can check code snippet. Can you help for this?

Code Examples:

```js
var myNum = document.getElementById('num');

myNum.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var dd = e.target.value.replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)(?!^)/g, ',')
  myNum.value = dd;
  console.log(dd);
});

// I expect like this:
console.log('592500000'.replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)(?!^)/g, ','));
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can first remove all commas so that the previous results do not affect the current result.

```js
var myNum = document.getElementById('num');

myNum.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var dd = e.target.value.replace(/,/g, '').replace(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)(?!^)/g, ',')
  myNum.value = dd;
  console.log(dd);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num">
```